# How to instantiate a type that is based on a closure

Tags: rust, closures

In my project I am using a type definition to hold closures with a specific function signature as shown below:

```
// Standardized function signature
pub type InternalOperation = impl Fn(Ast, Rc<RefCell<VTable>>, Rc<RefCell<FTable>>) -> Ctr;
pub struct ExternalOperation {
    // ...
    // The project is on gitlab called relish if you are interested
}

/* A stored function may either be a pointer to a function
 * or a syntax tree to eval with the arguments
 */
pub enum Operation {
    Internal(InternalOperation),
    External(ExternalOperation)
}

// function which does not need args checked
pub struct Function {
    pub function: Operation,
    // many more things like argument types and function name
}
```

I attempt to instantiate a function:

```
pub fn get_export(env_cfg: bool) -> Function {
    return Function{
        name: String::from("export"),
        loose_syms: true,
        eval_lazy: true,
        args: Args::Lazy(2),
        function: Operation::Internal(
            |a: Ast, b: Rc<RefCell<VTable>>, c: Rc<RefCell<FTable>>| -> Ctr {
                // so much logic here to manage variables in b
                // if env_cfg is true, entries in b are tied to environment variables 
        })
    }
}
```

But I am then greeted with the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/vars.rs:49:13
   |
49 | /             |a: Ast, b: Rc<RefCell<VTable>>, c: Rc<RefCell<FTable>>| -> Ctr {
50 | |                 let inner = a.borrow_mut();
51 | |                 match &inner.car {
52 | |                     Ctr::Symbol(identifier) => {
...  |
96 | |                 return Ctr::None;
97 | |             }
   | |_____________^ expected opaque type, found closure
   |
```

What I have tried:

- Declaring InternalOperation as an anonymous function. This works but then I cannot store a closure.
- I attempted to use InternalOperation(......) to declare the closure, which is incorrect according to syntax rules

I am using the closure here so that user configuration for my application can be used within the body of the function operation. Is it possible to use the closure in this way, or do I need to refactor my code to apply the env_cfg value in some other way?

Comment: Using `impl Trait` in type aliases is unstable. Have you enabled the feature `type_alias_impl_trait`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `type_alias_impl_trait` feature is turned on. If not, this code should not compile anyway because without this feature `impl Trait` is not allowed inside type aliases.

---

In theory, this feature should consider any use of the type alias a "defining use", i.e. a use we can infer the opaque type from. In practice, it is not (yet) implemented for many uses. AFAIK, currently only function return types are considered defining use.

In your case, however, you expect the compiler to infer the type from an expression. *It should know* that `Operation::Internal`'s first field is of type `InternalOperation`, and thus *it should know* that `InternalOperation` is the type of the callback inside `get_export()`. *In theory* this should work, except the compiler doesn't (currently) applies this knowledge.

You can workaround this by creating a new function to return the callback:

```rust
fn get_callback(env_cfg: bool) -> InternalOperation {
    |a: Ast, b: Rc<RefCell<VTable>>, c: Rc<RefCell<FTable>>| -> Ctr {
        // so much logic here to manage variables in b
        // if env_cfg is true, entries in b are tied to environment variables
    }
}
pub fn get_export(env_cfg: bool) -> Function {
    Function {
        name: String::from("export"),
        loose_syms: true,
        eval_lazy: true,
        args: Args::Lazy(2),
        function: Operation::Internal(get_callback(env_cfg)),
    }
}
```

Comment: When I refactor it to look like this I get the same error referencing the get_callback function's return value.

Comment: This is strange because it [does work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=adc9999f193da04d81547a04b903334b) for me. Can you provide more context?

Comment: Absolutely. I pushed a WIP commit to gitlab:
https://gitlab.com/whom/relish

The callback getter and Function instance is in src/vars.rs and the type definitions are in src/funcs.rs. My rustc version is 1.59.0-nightly and the feature stanza for ```type_alias_impl_trait``` is in both src/lib.rs and src/bin/main.rs

Any insight you have would be very welcome!

Comment: You use it twice with different closures. It should deduce to one, and only one, type.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I have removed every other use of that type alias save for the one used in the export function callback. I am still getting the same error.

Is it true that I cannot use this type alias with multiple closures that have the same matching signature? If so I will need to remove the use of this type alias and find another way to reference the closures.